# How to retrieve Artifacts BuildId consumed by a pipeline in Azure Devops REST API

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Azure Devops REST API.

I have an YAML pipeline (CD) that consumes an Artifact generated in a different pipeline (CI).

When I Fetch the artifacts [Build->Artifact/List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) I receive an empty list, but using the website I have 2 artifacts consumed.

Is there a way to retrieve via API the Build-Id that generated the artifact that has been consumed by the CD pipeline?

Already checked all the AZ Devops REST API documentation but couldn't find anything that could help.

Answer (score 0):

at present, we do not have the api to help us to check if the artifact has been consumed by the CD pipeline by using the build-ID.